# ubuntu isc-dhcp-server expected ip address or hostname

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I recently replaced my windows server with an ubuntu one and I was setting up dhcp when I ran into this error whilst trying to add a 'reserved' client.

```
expecting IP address or hostname
Jun  6 01:47:27 xee dhcpd: fixed-address:
Jun  6 01:47:27 xee dhcpd:               ^
Jun  6 01:47:27 xee dhcpd: Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
```

This is the section of the config:

```
host temple {
hardware ethernet ‎BC:5F:F4:A2:29:96;
fixed-address: 10.1.1.12;
}
```

From the material I've found online it should all work so I'm not too sure what is happening.

Edit: here is my entire config:

```
ddns-update-style none;

option domain-name "lan";
option domain-name-servers xee.home.lan;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;

subnet 10.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 10.1.1.3 10.1.1.253;
option routers 10.1.1.1;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.1.1.254;
option domain-name-servers 10.1.1.2, 8.8.8.8;
}

#host temple {
#hardware ethernet ‎BC:5F:F4:A2:29:96;
#fixed-address 10.1.1.12;
#}
```

The commented part when uncommented throws the error above.

Answer (score 0):

The should not be a colon after `fixed-address`.

This:

```
host temple {
hardware ethernet ‎BC:5F:F4:A2:29:96;
fixed-address: 10.1.1.12;
}
```

Should be this:

```
host temple {
hardware ethernet ‎BC:5F:F4:A2:29:96;
fixed-address 10.1.1.12;
}
```

Edit, based on the bigger context of the entire `dhcpd.conf` file:

Do not allocate your fixed address from the dynamic address reserved pool. Move the options to be global, so as to include the fixed addresses. I am suggesting this:

```
ddns-update-style none;

option routers 10.1.1.1;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.1.1.254;
option domain-name "home.lan";
option domain-name-servers 10.1.1.2, 8.8.8.8;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;

subnet 10.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 10.1.1.13 10.1.1.253;
}

host temple {
hardware ethernet ‎BC:5F:F4:A2:29:96;
fixed-address 10.1.1.12;
}
```

Comment: thanks for spotting that, still getting the same error though.

Comment: Then we need the bigger context. We need to see more of your `dhcpd.conf` file.

Comment: I've pasted in my entire config now.

Comment: I've made the changes you have suggested and still land on the same error, I'm starting to think this software is borked.

Comment: on further testing using the mac address 08:00:2b:4c:59:23 works but my own pc's mac address doesn't. Maybe this is a software bug.

Comment: try deleting `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases`, then re-boot, such that it has to be built again. A MAC such as you listed should work fine.

Comment: I had a quick look in dhcpd.leases and my computer is mentioned with the mac address listed above mapped to the ip 10.1.1.12 like I want... I really have no clue what is going on but at least it won't give out that ip to anything else. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which is why I suggested that you delete the file. That entry is left over from, I guess, when you were giving out that IP address from the dynamic pool.